# Autohotkey script for a single button translation to english

Tags: autohotkey

Can anyone help me to create a script in which

If I press F1 then It automatically right clicks the webpage/website which is currently opened on chrome browser and then select "translate to English"

**Note** Please make sure, It works with single key F1 and Click must be placed so as it works almost all the time for any webpage.
Sample is given in the picture.
[Right click and Translate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17OS6.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome:

```
F1:: ;When F1 is Clicked
Send {AppsKey} ;Opens the Page Right Click Menu, regardless of where the mouse is positioned
Send t ;Selects the Translate Option
return ;End Hotkey
```

Comment: @ManojPal If this solution solved your ploblem, could you please mark it as the accepted answer so that others know this question is resolved?